# A more optimized way of finding highest prime factor

Tags: java

I've solved Project Euler #3, but solving the same in Hacker Rank which has time constraint of < 4 seconds doesn't work. I've tried using the square root solution for speeding up but it fails.

Example:

The prime factors of 10000001 are 11 and 909091, we have sqrt(10000001) = 3162, if we check all primes from 2 to 3162, we can only have 11, after loop terminated, the result will be 11, incorrect answer.

So, when I use num/2 the running time is significantly increased.

```
public class Solution {

static boolean checkPrime(long num){
boolean toret = true;
long sq = (long) Math.sqrt(num);
for(long i=2; i<=sq; i++){
    if(num%i ==0)
        toret = false;
}
return toret;
}

static long gimmeAns(long num){
ArrayList<Long> al  = new ArrayList<Long>();
int q = 0;
long[] list = new long[10];
long sq = (long)Math.sqrt(num);
long sqint;
boolean flag = true;
if(num < 0){
    for(long i =3; i<=num; i+=2){
    if(num%i == 0)
        al.add(i);
        }
}else{
    //for(long i =3; i<=sq; i+=2){
    //if(num%i == 0)
        //al.add(i);
        //}
    boolean isPrimeCheck = checkPrime(num);
    if(isPrimeCheck){
        al.add(num);
    }
    for(long i =3 ; i<= num/2 ; i+=2){
        if(num%i==0){
            al.add(i);

        }
    }
}
Iterator it = al.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    long curr = (long) it.next();
     flag = true;
    long squrt = (long) Math.sqrt(curr);
        for(long i=2; i<=squrt; i++){
            if(curr%i == 0)
                flag = false;
        }
    if(flag == true){

        list[q++] = curr;
    }
}

return list[q-1];

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long numberCases;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    numberCases = in.nextLong();
    long result = 0;
    for(long i=0; i< numberCases; i++){
        long num = in.nextLong();
        result = gimmeAns(num);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Well you can return the co-prime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about iterating over all *sqrt(n)* numbers. Each time you find a prime, you divide the number by that prime (and do no increase the number).

Now when you have reached *sqrt(n)* you compare the latest found divider with the remaining number. You have to return the maximum of the two:

```
long n = sc.nextLong();
int k = 0x02;
int l = (int) (Math.sqrt(n)+1);
while(k < n && k <= l) {
    if(n%k == 0) {
        n /= k;
    } else {
        k++;
    }
}
return Math.max(n,k);
```

In this case if a number has two primes, the smaller one will be captured in the while loop resulting in the fact that `n` will now have the larger value.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to check the numbers backward. Instead of checking from 2 to 3162, you should try checking from 3162 to 2.

Comment: This won't necessary generate *prime factors*. For instance if the input is `12`, it will check from `11` (?) to `2` resulting in `6`, but `6=2*3`...